# Добавить текст с edit в memo

Tags: c++, c++builder

Мне нужно добавить текст с edit в memo в одну строку.
Пробовал такой код, но не понимаю его смысла:

```
char nazva[15];
strcpy(nazva, Edit1->Text.c_str());
float price = StrToFloat(Edit2->Text);
int kol = StrToInt(Edit3->Text);

fprintf(f, "%s %6.2f %i\n", nazva, price, kol);
fclose(f);
Edit1->Clear();
Edit2->Clear();
Edit3->Clear();
Edit1->SetFocus();
```

Comment: А что хотите от нас - чтения хелпа или книжки с выражением? Будьте поконкретнее.

Comment: Помогите с кодом для решения моей задачи. Если Вы считаете, что тот код, который я записал в своём вопросе, подходит, то объясните его мне пожалуйста

Comment: Также забыл учесть о том, что этот код предназначен для записывания текста с edit'ов в ново создавшийся текстовый файл. А мне нужно, чтобы сперва текст с edit'а выводился на memo, а уж потом сохранялся в ново создавшийся текстовый файл

Answer (score 0):

```
    char nazva[30];
   char kod_INN[30];
   char ed_izm[10];

    strcpy(nazva, Edit1->Text.c_str());
    strcpy(kod_INN, Edit2->Text.c_str());
    strcpy(ed_izm, Edit3->Text.c_str()); функция strcpy копирует значение 
                            переведённой строки из типа string в тип char

   int kol = StrToInt(Edit4->Text);
   float price_not_PDV = StrToFloat(Edit5->Text);
   float summa_not_PDV = StrToFloat(Edit6->Text);

     Memo1->Clear();

   AnsiString str; // объявляем переменную для строки AnsiString
      str.printf("%s %s %s %d %4.2f %4.2f\n", nazva, kod_INN,
      ed_izm, kol, price_not_PDV, summa_not_PDV); // для переменной str записуем функцию printf
     Memo1->Lines->Add(str);
```

Comment: Это ответ? .....

Comment: Да, это ответ. С помощью этого кода можно добавлять текст с edit в memo